# Can Spring Application have multiple IOC containers and multiple DispatcherServlets?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, inversion-of-control

I was going through some core **Spring Concepts** and came across **DispatcherServlet** and **IOC Container/ApplicationContext**.
Is it possible to have multiple IOC containers in the same Spring Boot application? If yes, how to create them and in what scenarios will they be required?
(https://coderanch.com/t/563755/frameworks/Spring-Multiple-IoC-Containers-Singleton)
Is it possible to have multiple DispatcherServlets in Spring Boot application. If yes, how are they created and why they might be required?
I found something related to this here-
[https://www.interviewbit.com/spring-interview-questions/#:~:text=Spring%20MVC%20allows%20instantiating%20multiple%20DispatcherServlet%20and%20each%20of%20them%20have%20multiple%20contexts%20specific%20to%20them.%20They%20can%20have%20the%20same%20root%20context%20too](https://www.interviewbit.com/spring-interview-questions/#:%7E:text=Spring%20MVC%20allows%20instantiating%20multiple%20DispatcherServlet%20and%20each%20of%20them%20have%20multiple%20contexts%20specific%20to%20them.%20They%20can%20have%20the%20same%20root%20context%20too).